# Upgrade from Magento CE 1.5.1 to Enterprise Edition 1.12 or later

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-community

I have Magento community edition 1.5.1 and I want to upgrade to Enterprise Edition 1.12 or later.

Is it possible to upgrade from CE to EE directly without any intermediate step?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no magic button to do this.

It involves 2 part: 
first - upgrade your community to the latest version . (each community version has its corresponding enterprise version, if you like to keep an old version , then just skip it)

second - migrate community to enterprise

As DB schema is different, and depends on your customization, it is much safe to follow approach:

1. Backup your app/design , app/code/local , app/code/community, media/
2. Extract the clean magento enterprise web files to a new server
3. Extract your backup file to the enterprise web files
4. Connect the webfiles in (3) with the existing community db, then setup script will run automatically

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Leo.  I can download and install a clean magento enterprise and reapply the EE extension manually (not use the CE code at all).  Is there a data migration tool to simply migrate CE data(mysql) to EE.

Comment: As i know, there is no data migration tool from community to enterprise.
For the database,  i would suggest 2 approahes:
1) as i suggested in #4, just connect to your existing db, the db setup script in enterprise web files will auto upgrade your  db , so you dont need to migrate your data (but higher risk to face error)
2) use the clean enterprise db, and export specific community tables into it. But you need to be very clearly about which tables you need to export e.g. core_config_data, sales_flat_order, 

i think you can backup the db and try approach 1 first.